# Chrome extension, options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

use this code, from chrome extens documentation

```
        $('#go-to-options').bind('click', function() {
            if (chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage) {
            // New way to open options pages, if supported (Chrome 42+).
                chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
            } else {
            // Reasonable fallback.
                window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html'));
            }
        });
```

It gives an error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

How do I open a options page? By clicking on the button?

Comment: The given error can't be occurring in that part of the code - there is no `create` mentioned anywhere. In the Chrome console, every error is accompanied by a file name + line number (clickable, shown at the right end of the line), which should tell you exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: This error occurs when I try to call chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage() in the console. When I press the button, I redirect to about:blank